# Como solucionar esse erro corretamente?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-services

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20LogUserService
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
at http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:40:307
at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:308)
at http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:40:381
at d (http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:308)
at e (http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:64)
at Object.g.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:213)
at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:501)
at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8080/web/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js:39:96)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma boa dica é sempre acessar os links que o angular gera quando ele aponta que ocorreu um erro.

Por exemplo http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20LogUserService

O próprio angular já está te dizendo o problema e ainda dando a resposta quando você acessa o link.

> Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- LogUserService

Ele não conseguiu localizar a dependência do seu controller LogUserService para poder injetar nele.

Tenha certeza que você criou o Service e importou o arquivo javascript onde ele foi criando.

Também tenha certeza que estar injetando o $scope service no seu controller.

O angular trabalha enssencialmente com **injeção de dependência** e isso faz com que ele ao não localizar uma dependência do seu controller quebre a aplicação exatamente para evitar acesso a recursos não explícitos.

Dúvidas sobre isso, de uma pesquisada no google sobre Injeção de Dependência.

Comment: Erick fiz injeção de dependencia exatamente como ele diz que deve ser feito mas mesmo assim ele continua dando esse erro, você conhece alguma maneira de realizar um debug para verificar exatamente o os problemas?

Comment: @VictorSiqueira consegue postar o código do seu controller e a parte do seu HTML onde você importa os javascripts? De qualquer modo, você pode instalar a extensão AngularJS Batarang (stable) version no chrome para te ajudar. Só funciona no chrome.

Comment: Olá Erick, descobri qual era o erro, eu estava colocando no service o paramentro $scope, e olhando a documentação que que um servioce não  pode depender de $scope

Answer (score 2):

Você está tentando usar `$scope`, porém a função qaue define seu controller ou similar não está referenciando `$scope` para injeção. Algo similar a isso:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', [function () {
    $scope.varContent = true; // Erro: $scope está faltando
}]);
```

Passe a referência, assim:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  // Do something with myService
}]);
```